# Why not one fundamental quantum field instead of several?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, string-theory

Why in the physics of elementary particles is not considered the option of the existence of not several separate, but only one single fundamental quantum field? Like string theory. One fundamental field, different vibration modes of which correspond to different particles.

Comment: The premise of your question is confusing, since you claim elementary particle physicists don't consider something, but then give the example of string theory doing that thing. I also think this kind of question, "why don't people do X", is very difficult to answer, unless you give some reason why you think X is a good idea. Otherwise the answer is just... people don't do X because X isn't a useful idea.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is not such a thing. Quantum fields are classified by finite-dimensional representations of the Lorentz group and relativistic particles by unitary representations of the Poincaré group. We can embed particles into fields and then the Poincaré transformation of particle states is connected in a specific way to the Lorentz transformation of the field. In turn this determines which particles each field can encode. There is no such field that may encode all particles. The details of this are in Weinberg's QFT textbook Chapter 5.

Comment: In string theory, the opposite is true. All particles are encoded by one field.

Comment: @Apmah, too bad string theory doesn't describe our universe.

Comment: The simplest possible setup in superstring theory would still have two fields... one bosonic and one fermionic. Similarly, you can reduce the number of fields somewhat in 4d QFT if you believe grand unification.

Comment: @nielsnielsen  this is still an open research question. string theories could model our universe and embed our present standard model data, in principle , if the correct  theory among the plethora could be established.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Number_of_solutions . It needs an Einstein thinking outside the box , imo.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян That's not correct. You would have a string field, which is a massive generalization of the fields we talk about in QFT. 1 string field = an infinite collection of QFT-type fields, of the kind described in Gold's answer. Each QFT-type field is typically associated with one particle. This generalization is useful in some approaches to string theory, but not useful for describing particle physics experiments done to date.

Comment: @Andrew But all these fields are part of a single physical system.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян Hm, seems you are moving the goal posts of your question, which didn't use the words "physical system." Anyway, for describing particle physics experiments, where string theory is not helpful, different standard model particles are different physical systems.

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean that, for example, the electromagnetic field and the electron-positron field in the standard model are separate interacting systems? In the same way, they can be considered as subsystems of one system, although from a practical point of view, all this is useless.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян Yes, they are separate but interacting systems. There's not a useful way I know of where you can think of them as part of one system (unless you try for something like string theory, like you said, but then the unification only becomes apparent and useful at Planck-scale energies). Some differences include... the photon is massless while the electron has a mass, the photon is a boson while the electron is a fermion, the photon interacts with electrically charged particles while the electron interacts with the electromagnetic and weak force bosons.

Comment: @Andrew As far as I understand, this interaction is constant and continuous.